# How do i remove the top box-shadow of a dropdown-menu in CSS?

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I need help. How do i remove the top box-shadow in css? 
Here is a image: https://picr.ws/images/b004e226b4eeb5616aa9d0bfdcb61b95.png

I have here a live-demo: [www.hobbu.org](http://www.hobbu.org)

and here some snippets:

html

```
<nav>
  <ul class="container_12">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Einstellungen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ausloggen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extras</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li:after {
  margin-top: -2px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #ff4081;
  transform: scaleX(0.0001);
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.0001);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0.0001);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;

}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: #212121;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li > ul {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li > ul li {
  line-height: 35px;
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

nav ul li > ul li:after {
  margin-top: -3px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-bottom: solid 0px transparent;
}

nav ul li > ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff4081;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

i already have set the dropdown z-index but the problem is, both the nav and dropdown has the same box-shadow

Sorry for my bad english, im from germany.

Comment: Can you post some html?  It's hard to tell what exactly you're doing

Comment: It's coming form that white menu above it, you could try setting the z-index of the drop down higher than the menu above it with the drop shadow. Should post the css/html and we can show you how to fix it :).

Comment: Your English is better than many native English speakers. :)

Comment: You do not want to remove the box-shadow from CSS? Why?

Comment: I only want to remove the top box-shadow from the dropdown, the rest dont. look at the image or visit the the live-demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your dropdown's css to this:

```
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.16);
```

Comment: This will increase the shadow on the bottom side.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, your question can be merely resolved through an underrated characteristic of `box-shadow`:

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches **one or more** drop-shadows to the box. The property takes a comma-separated list of shadows, **ordered front to back**. Each shadow is given as a <shadow>, represented by 2-4 length values, an optional color, and an optional ‘inset’ keyword.
>   <shadow> = inset? && {2,4} && ?

Your current `box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)` is **only one** of the possible <shadow>s as stated above.

You can simply prepend it with a first (so front) <shadow> with the desired characteristics, like:
`box-shadow: #fff 0 -5px, 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)`, where the 1st  instance has:

- `#fff` has to be the same color as the master `<ul>` color
- `0` makes no horizontal (right) shadow
- `-5px`makes a vertical (natively down, but here up since the minus sign) shadow, which is just what you need to hide the top shadow generated by your previous unique (and now 2nd)  instance

Then you have to manage with your red `<ul>` border-bottom, because now it is hidden also: it's up to you to imagine which method to use for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since, from your question I can interpret that you do not want to remove the box-shadow property from either of the elements (which according to me is the right thing to do), you can enclose the sub menu (the inner `<ul>` element) inside another element (like a `<div>`) and the change the CSS of the inner `<ul>` and outer `<div>` to hide the top shadow and keep showing all the other shadows.

I have created a fiddle for the solution. You can check it here.
http://jsfiddle.net/c5nLay4L/2/

[image: This is how the end result looks]

Basically what we are doing is that the outer `<div>` (the one with `class = "submenu-container"`) has been set to hide anything that goes outside its boundaries (by using `overflow: hidden`). This way all shadows would get hidden. But we want to hide just the top shadow. Hence I added `padding` to all sides of the container `<div>` except the top. This way, the `<div>` is now big enough to show all other shadows except the top. Then you position this outer div (with `position: absolute` and `top: 50px` to bring it in the same position as the inner submenu `<ul>` (and of course remove the positioning styles from `<ul>`)

**Reason why changing z-index won't work**
The effect of changing the z-index depends on the stacking context of the element with the z-index and its parent's stacking context.

You can read about it here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

When you give the `nav` element a higher z-index that means the parent now has a stacking context. Changing the `z-index` of the inner `<ul>` is moving the `ul` within this parent context. Hence it cannot go under that `<nav>`.

To understand it better, consider a chair with a book kept on it. You lift the chair, the book rises with it. You lift the book, only the book rises, nothing happens to the chair. But the book cannot go under the seat of the chair even if you force it to. It can only rise above the seat of the chair. Unless of course you move the chair from under the book. Then the book falls below the chair. Here the chair is your `<nav>`. Book is the inner submenu `<ul>`. Only if you change the stacking context to avoid this parent-child container relationship, will the z-index start taking effect